# Find the sum of all $x$, $1 \le x \le 100$, such that $7$ divides $x^2+15x+1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the sum of all $x$, $1 \le x \le 100$, such that $7$ divides
>   $x^2+15x+1$.

I am clueless about how to approach this problem.

Trying some values of $x$ I've found $2,4,9,11,16$ to satisfy the restriction after that I found it to be harder to find another good $x$.

I think I have to solve $x^2+15x+1 \equiv 0 \mod 7$ for $x$.

Solving this I would get $x \equiv \sqrt{\cfrac{13}{2}} -\cfrac{15}{2}$ but this doesn't help as I would get this result for any modulo $n$...

Comment: We may as well work modulo $7$, in which case we are looking for $x$ such that $x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$. But then it's enough to check $x$ for each of the residue classes $0, \ldots, 6$ modulo $7$.

Comment: @Travis Where does the condition $x^2+x+1 \equiv 0 $ follow from ?

Comment: Oh I see it $15x=14x+x$...

Comment: I try to make again some effort,thanks !

Comment: You missed $2$...

Comment: You should get the sum: $$2+4+(2+7)+(4+7)+(2+14)+(4+14)+\cdots (2+91)+(4+91)+(2+98).$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Another hint**:  Once you get used to replacing coefficients with modular equivalents, it's useful to note that $x^2+15x+1\equiv x^2+x-6$ mod $7$, because then what you need to solve is

$$(x+3)(x-2)\equiv0\mod7$$

Comment: So $7| (x+3) $ or $7|(x-2)$ .Got it,thanks for the hint !

Comment: @Mr.Y, precisely.  Note, however, it's a simple as that only because $7$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** You have to solve 
$$x^2+x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$

Modulo $7$ $x$ is equivalent to its remainder. So check which numbers between 0 and 6 satisfy your relation, and then which numbers between $1$ and 100 (formula, do not check them 1 by 1) are equivalent with those two remainders...

Comment: $x^2+x+1 \equiv 0 \mod 7 \implies (x^2+x+\cfrac{1}{4} )+\cfrac{3}{4} \equiv 0 \mod 7 \implies \left(x+\cfrac{1}{2} \right)^2 \equiv -\cfrac{3}{4} \mod 7 $....How do I take the square root now ?Should I leave the equation as it is without factoring ?

Comment: @Mr.Y You don't need to take the square roots. All you have to do is check which numbers between 0 and 6 work and use the fact that every number is congruent with its remainder..... If you want to take the square roots, you are talking about quadratic residues, but something tells me you didn't cover that YET.

Answer (score 1):

A table of $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb F_7$ gives for $1,2,3,4,5,6,0$ the values $3,7,6,7,10,8,1$ respectively. Hence the only numbers to be considered are of the form $7m+2$ and $7m+4$.

We have $$2+(2+7)+(2+14)+.....+(2+14\cdot7)=\frac{15(100+2)}{2}=765$$
$$4+(4+7)+(4+14)+.........+(4+13\cdot7)=\frac{14(95+4)}{2}=693$$

Thus the asked sum is $765+693=\color{red}{1458}$